# can't load geojson file into azure maps using javascript, but gives 404 error

Tags: javascript, razor-pages, azure-maps

I am attempting to load a geojson file in azure maps, I am building a standard razor pages web app in visual studio. The geojson files are in a folder called 'data', but when I try to load the files I get a 404 error, but I can't seem to figure out how I can figure out where the files are put when building and running the server. According to the error it's trying to load 'https://localhost:7128/data/file0.geojson'
I have attached some screenshots to show my current setup[file structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VnNgq.png)[function loads file into maps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VsRLL.png)

I have tried to move the folder to different locations, tried different syntaxes for the file url, all with the same result, a 404 error. I also tried to load the file using the full local folder and file name, but that gave me an error saying that it's not allowed to load local files

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) on how to improve the quality of your question. Then [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77426639/edit) your question to include your source code as a working [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), which can be tested by others to provide an answer faster. [Please do not upload images of code/errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aside from possibly not having the right path, I suspect the issue may be with the `.geojson` extension. Try changing it to `.json` and see if it works. If it does, then the issue is that you need to allow the `.geojson` extension to be served from your app. You can do this:

```cs
// Set up custom content types - associating file extension to MIME type
var provider = new FileExtensionContentTypeProvider();

// Add new mappings
provider.Mappings[".geojson"] = "application/json";

app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
{
    ContentTypeProvider = provider
});
```

If changing to `.json` didn't work, then you either have an incorrect path or need to allow your app to serve static files: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-7.0

Comment: thanks a lot, i had to move the folder inside of the wwwroot folder and add the contentprovider, but now it works